# SQL Server Keys and Index Help

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, key, indexing

Im trying to use Keys and Indexson a database and having difficulty. My requirements are as follows:

1. I want to be able to have empty string values in the Document No column as well as values
2. The constraint should check for Unique Values based on a DatabaseID and DocumentNo ( eg you can have the same document no for 2 different database ID's)

The table is similar to this (Extra columns removed for simplicity)

```
RecordID (bigint)
DocumentNo (varchar(12))
DatabaseID (bigint)
```

So the constraint should not allow inserting or updating a record if there is already a document no for the specified document no and database ID. A blank document no should be allowed to be entered as there are multiple rows with no document no.

Is this possible? if so please could you let me know how.

EDIT:
Here is the Query to Create the View and Constraint:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
    CREATE VIEW vNoDuplicateDoNos
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
    AS
        SELECT [PODocumentNo],[SageDatabaseID]
        FROM dbo.[Order]
        WHERE [PODocumentNo] <> ''
    GO
    --Create an index on the view.
    CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_V1_ID 
        ON vNoDuplicateDoNos ([PODocumentNo],[SageDatabaseID]);
    GO
```

Comment: You don't use the Check Constraint Expression Builder Dialog for this. You need the indexes and keys dialog to create unique constraints.

Comment: Can I achieve the above with allowing an empty column, and to check a unique value based on 2 columns?

Comment: WraithNath - What you want to allow duplicates if the column is blank? Yes you need a unique filtered index (if SQL Server 2008) or an indexed view with a unique index on it. There are questions on SO already that cover this.

Comment: Hi Martin, the only duplicates I want to include is an empty string. I want the table to allow multiple rows with nothing in the document no column, but if there is a value then it must be unique for each Database ID. I just had a look at the keys and index forms. It does look like it almost there but how to allow for empty values? - Im now searching SO for more info. nothing obvious came up on google but I was not searching for keys and indexes

Comment: I agree with @Martin about the Unique Filtered Index. That should be listed below as the Answer to this Question.

Comment: @ srutzky - Ill edit the question to reference the correct terminology for the requirement. Its not answered yet as all my requirements are not met. Ill +1 for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about using the GUI for this, but you should use a UNIQUE INDEX with a WHERE condition (assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 or newer):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UIX_TableName_DocumentNo_DatabaseID
ON dbo.TableName
(DocumentNo, DatabaseID)
WHERE DocumentNo <> ''
ON IndexesFileGroup -- omit this line if you do not have a File Group for Indexes
```

Also, I was not able to find an option for the WHERE condition via the GUI in the "Manage Indexes and Keys" dialog.

To be fair, this was suggested by "Martin" in a comment on the Question.  I just felt it needed to be explicitly stated with an example.

IF you are using a version of SQL Server prior to 2008 (when Filtered Indexes were added), you can use a Trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TableName_PreventDuplicatesTrigger
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF (EXISTS(
                SELECT  1
                FROM    dbo.TableName tn
                INNER JOIN  INSERTED ins
                        ON  ins.DocumentNo = tn.DocumentNo
                        AND ins.DatabaseID = tn.DatabaseID
                WHERE   ins.DocumentNo <> ''
        ))
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR('Duplicate DocumentNo/DatabaseID combination detected!', 16, 1)
    END
GO
```

The above trigger will look for any existing records that match the two fields but only if the inserted or updated DocumentNo is not empty.  If found, it calls ROLLBACK which will cancel the INSERT or UPDATE statement and the RAISERROR will display a message as to what caused the ROLLBACK.

Another option when using a version of SQL Server prior to 2008 is to create an Indexed View on DocumentNo and DatabaseID while filtering out empty DocumentNo records.  This was suggested by "Martin" in the comments to this Answer.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.UniqueDocumentAndDatabase
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  DocumentNo, DatabaseID
    FROM    dbo.TableName
    WHERE   DocumentNo <> ''
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX_UniqueDocumentAndDatabase
ON dbo.UniqueDocumentAndDatabase
(DocumentNo, DatabaseID)
GO
```

Please note that the two SET options as well as the WITH SCHEMABINDING are required for Indexed Views. It is also required that SET ANSI_NULLS ON was used when creating the base table.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the query. I have removed the GUI requirement - I just wanted to Use it as I could not work out why anything I put in there didnt pass validation. Anyway, I have run the script above (changing details to actual columns etc) and Im getting an error: Invalid filegroup 'IndexesFileGroup' specified.
 Do I need to change the last bit to something else?

Comment: @WraithNath - make it whatever your filegroup is instead of `IndexesFileGroup` - if you don't know, try `PRIMARY`

Comment: @WraithNath, the final "ON" option to specify a FileGroup is just best practice (i.e. to have a separate File Group for Indexes as opposed to the base table data).  If you do not have this, just leave that option off entirely.  I will update the answer to make a comment about that.

Comment: Thanks JNK - that worked. Ill mark this as the answer so its clear for other SO users to get to the solution. - Thanks all for your help

Comment: Just another quick one - Just realised Filtered index's were only added on 2008 - client is running 2005. Is there any equivalent?

Comment: @WraithNath, I am not aware of any equivalent prior to SQL Server 2008.  I can update my answer to include a suggestion for using an AFTER INSERT trigger if still on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @ srutzky - Thanks, I would appreciate it if you could. I dont mind listing a new question for an alternative to your query above. This whole problem stems from a bug im trying to investigate. somehow an data from one record is being updated to another record in my software and im trying to identify from where. If i can get SQL to throw an error when a record is updated or inserted then the data layer should log this with the associated stack trace. If only the client was on SQL 2008- its like looking for a needle in a haystack at the moment!

Comment: @WraithNath, I just updated the answer. I don't think it needs a new question since it is really the same thing: how to prevent duplicates with the caveat of the empty field. It is just two different implementations based on what version of SQL Server someone is using.

Comment: @srutzky - You would create an indexed View in previous versions `SELECT DocumentNo, DatabaseID FROM dbo.TableName WHERE DocumentNo <> ''` and put the unique clustered index on `DocumentNo, DatabaseID`

Comment: @Martin, thanks for that suggestion. I will add that to my answer for completeness and credit you.

Comment: @srutzky and @Martin - thanks ill give the trigger a go. I was just reading something about creating the indexed view. Im trying to avoid code changes and recompiling the app and it looks like I would need to insert into the view rather than the table which I would have to change code to do. - unless im misunderstanding and any updates / inserts into the main table would cause the view to change the error

Comment: @WraithNath - You are misunderstanding. Your code can ignore the View it is only there to enforce the unique constraint. Certain `SET` options need to be on when you insert or update to the base table but in SQL Server 2005 these will probably be on anyway. (unlike SQL Server 2000 where the default for `ARITH_ABORT` caused problems)

Comment: @Martin - thanks for clearing that up. The view will be easier to find and remove after I have got to the bottom of the error so ill test both methods. Thanks again.

Comment: @WraithNath and @Martin: I have added the Indexed View example to the Answer.

Comment: @WraithNath: you are welcome and also thanks to Martin for his suggestions.